# Create a file in C programming and write "Hello world!" in the file

Tags: c, file

I have tried this code on my device, and it creates a file named "hello.usr" and prints the text "Hello world!" successfully.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{    
    FILE *opening;
    opening = fopen("hello.usr","w");
    fprintf(opening,"Hello world!");     
    fclose(opening);
    printf("Writing to the file was successful.\n");
    printf("Closing the program");
    return 0;
}
```

But the online judge where I'm submitting this program gives me an error. **Your program's output is shorter than expected**

How can I overcome this?

---

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728472/create-a-file-in-c-programming-and-write-hello-world-in-the-file#comment137031755_77728472) says:

> Write a program that prints the text "Hello world!" into the file "hello.usr". The file does not exist, so it must be created. Finally, the program must print a message on the screen indicating that writing to the file was successful. The text printed to the file must exactly match the assignment. Example output: Writing to the file was successful. Closing the program. The output of the program must be exactly the same as the example output (the most strict comparison level).

Comment: Should we know precisely what the online judge is asking?

Comment: _Your program's output_ - is that the output from the `printf` statements? Maybe it wants a newline or a `.` at the end?

Comment: It the test possibly expecting a newline '\n' at the end?

Comment: @001 no... it's below the output section where the online judge tries to read the line from the file.

Comment: @TenG tried it too. same error.

Comment: If you can't link to the assignment I suggest you re-read it carefully several times, to see what you might have missed (which might have transferred to your previous supposed description).

Comment: I notice that you output `"Writing to the file was successful."` but you *haven't checked* **anything** and so you don't know. Not the file opening, not the output, nor that closing were successful. Those three functions return a value for a *reason*. Perhaps there is more to the assignment than you revealed, or understood.

Comment: I've transferred your comment about the "full problem" into the question, but there's no formatting in there.  You should improve the layout, especially if the full problem specifies that the messages are on two lines, etc.  Most likely, you have problems because you're not terminating your outputs with a newline — the `fprintf()` to the file and the last `printf()` are missing the newlines (and the last `printf()` doesn't have a full stop (period, dot) at the end of the line either).  Normally, lines end with a newline — omitting them is a common mistake by novices.

Comment: Contuining with teh "your out put legnth" hint, is this on Windows? If so try "\c\r" instead of "\n". Also, some "Hello world!" examples use "Hello, world!" - note the comma. If all else fails just keeping adding a space at the end until it passes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by online judge, but it's a good thing to use *"`\n`"* at the end of your writes. *"`\n`"* is the special character that jumps a line.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{    
    FILE *opening;
    opening = fopen("hello.usr","w");
    fprintf(opening,"Hello world!\n"); // Here    
    fclose(opening);
    printf("Writing to the file was successful. Closing the program");
    return 0;
}
```

Reading your comment now, I don't think the solution is related to *"`\n`"*'s.

Some other good things you should consider are:

- Adding blank spaces after your *","*
- Maybe add some blank lines for your own comprehension

If I was going to write the same things, I'd do like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>    

int main() {    
    FILE* file = fopen("hello.usr", "w");
    fprintf(file, "Hello world!");

    fclose(file);
    printf("Writing to the file was successful. Closing the program.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried it too. unfortunately same error.

Comment: well, I just read your comment now, I think maybe the two last messages have to be together (if you didn't write it wrong)

Comment: I edited this, try the new one

Comment: okay, i'm trying this new one.

Comment: can you send me the url for that thing you're doing?

Comment: I wish I could. It's an open credit course in which I've enrolled. [link](https://campusonline.fi/en/course/c-programming-2/) You won't really see anything without enrollment.

Comment: this seems to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989919/create-a-file-in-c-programming-and-write-hello-world-in-the-file), but those responses aren't really straight to point as well. Do you really need to pass by that?